# How do I get a piece of JSONObject, inside a JSONObject, with a parameter? In Java

Tags: java, json, iterator

I want to return a specific object in my JSON called a 'batch'. It has a batch ID and multiple questions. Questions have a question ID, name and mark.
Here is an example JSON:

```
{
  "batch" {
    "b_id" : "5",
    "question" : {
        "q_id" : "3",
        "name" : "foo",
        "mark" : "3"
    }
    "question" : { 
        "q_id" : "4",
        "name" : "bar",
        "mark" : "10"
},

"batch" {//b_id and questions}
}
```

I am not very experienced in JSON, but I tried to do it with an Iterator because it has the `Map` interface. Here is my method:

```
public JSONObject getBatch(int id) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, JSONException {
JSONObject batches = getAllBatches(); //this is the above mentioned JSONObject
Iterator<?> keys = batches.keys(); //something I took from another StackOverflow answer
while(keys.hasNext()){
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    if(batches.get(key) instanceof JSONObject){
    //Here I don't know!
    //if a value is found with b_id = 5, then return that specific batch!
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

Now I do not know what to put in between the iterator itself. If anyone could help me, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The sample JSON you have above doesn't seem valid.  I think this is what you need:

```
{
  "batches" : 
    [
      {
        "b_id" : 5,
        "questions" : 
          [
            {
              "q_id" : "3",
              "name" : "foo",
              "mark" : "3" 
            }, 
            {  
              "q_id" : "4", 
              "name" : "bar", 
              "mark" : "10"
            }
          ] 
      },
      {
        "b_id" : 6,
        "questions" : 
          [
            {
              "q_id" : "4",
              "name" : "foo", 
              "mark" : "4" 
            }, 
            {  
              "q_id" : "5", 
              "name" : "bar", 
              "mark" : "11"
            }
          ] 
       }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code to get the JSON object:

```
public static JSONObject getBatch(JSONObject json, int id) {
    JSONArray batches = json.getJSONArray("batches");
    for (int i=0; i < batches.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject batch = batches.getJSONObject(i);
        Integer batchId = (Integer)batch.get("b_id");
        if (batchId == id) {
            return batch;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

here is the main method I used to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input =
        "{\"batches\" : ["
        + "{\"b_id\" : 5,\"questions\" : [{\"q_id\" : \"3\",\"name\" : \"foo\",\"mark\" : \"3\" }, {  \"q_id\" : \"4\", \"name\" : \"bar\", \"mark\" : \"10\"}] },"
        + "{\"b_id\" : 6,\"questions\" : [{\"q_id\" : \"4\",\"name\" : \"foo\",\"mark\" : \"4\" }, {  \"q_id\" : \"5\", \"name\" : \"bar\", \"mark\" : \"11\"}] }"
        + "] "
        + "}";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(input);
    System.out.println(getBatch(json, 5));
}
```

Tested with: json-20140107.jar